# Entering string into textbox.value (JavaScript) via button (asp.net)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, button, textbox

I am using Microsoft Visual Web developer 2010. I have a textbox (txtBoxInput) using the code: `<input type="text" id="txtBoxInput"/>`

I also have an aspn.net button (btnTest) using the code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button"/>
```

And the code in btnTest's event:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string test = txtBoxInput.Value = "test123";
}
```

However txtBoxInput control is not detected.
Is there a way where writing this C#/aspn.net code can put this string (test) into txtBox.Value.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `runat="server"`. Otherwise input won't be visible on server side and you'll need to access posted value trough `Request.Form` collection.

```
<input runat="server" type="text" id="txtBoxInput"/>
```